# kibana dashboard not updating

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, auto-update

I am using ELK stack for my logs. This is my architecture:

filebeat => Logstash => Elasticsearch <=> Kibana

Now I am making dashboards corresponding to my indices in Elasticsearch. The problem is that my dashboards are not getting updated even though new logs are coming. I did AUTO REFRESH too but no success. It used to work fine when I was learning ELK but now its not working as it ought to. What can be the issue ? There are only 10 windows corresponding to the logs in the dashboard and that window size is not increasing. It reamains as 1 2 3 4......10. Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

The Discovery search panel is designed to show a set subset of records, not all available records.Showing all the records is a bad option because it will lead to more usage of memory . This setting can be changed by going to the advance settings and changing the value of discovery:sampleSize but doing this will increase the latency as well as memory used .